# path defined in linux style a final variable. Can't open the path on windows

Tags: java

I don't know what to search for.
I have a external jar library in which there is a class that has all the configurations variables like where to store the log files and such, as public static final variables.
the path for log file config given is "/home/log.cfg". 
Now I am working in windows. How do I make a path like this? where to put the cfg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file can still be opened an read if you create the directory `home` in the root of your drive. Just make sure that the working directory of the application is on the same drive. Java file handling API seems to add the dirve letter to an absolute path if none was specifyed.

javadoc for [File#getAbsolutePath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29)

> On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user directory.

A simple test demonstrates that:

Create a directory under `C:\` named `home` and place some text file inside.

```
@Test
public void openFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File("/home/log.cfg");
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/log.cfg");
    int c;
    while(-1 != (c = fileInputStream.read())) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
}
```

And here is the output:

```
C:\home\log.cfg
Hello, log.fg!
```

Comment: Ah, nice to know that the root drive is redundant.

Comment: Thank you very much :) :)
I knew about making a 'home' directory but did not know that it's resolved against the current user directory. I was running the program in D drive and I made the folder in C drive as a result it could not find it.